# Calling zlib (C code) from a C++ file

Tags: c++, c

I have a `.cpp` file that contains the following function to decompress a file via `zlib`:

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <fstream>
bool gzip_uncompress(std::string &compressed_file_path,std::string &uncompressed_file_path)
{
    char outbuffer[1024*16];
    gzFile infile = (gzFile)gzopen(compressed_file_path, "rb");
    FILE *outfile = fopen(uncompressed_file_path, "wb");
    gzrewind(infile);
    while(!gzeof(infile))
    {
        int len = gzread(infile, outbuffer, sizeof(outbuffer));
        fwrite(outbuffer, 1, len, outfile);
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    gzclose(infile);
    return true;
}
```

This looks like it should run to me, but I'm getting compile time errors stating:

```
No matching function call to 'gzopen'
```

and

```
No matching function call to 'fopen'
```

The only thing I can thing of is that I am calling these in a `C++` file, and the `zlib` is a `C` library. I'm not sure about the `fopen` error though.

Does anyone see how I can call these functions and get around the compile error?

I hava also tried:

```
extern "C" {
   #include <zlib.h>
}
```

but still no go. Am I barking up the wrong tree? Should I move this function into a `C` file? But then I'd presumable have the same issue.

Comment: You're forcing a std::string into `gzopen(compressed_file_path, "rb");`. gzopen can't possibly take a `std::string`. Use `.c_str()`.

Comment: Ahhhh....you're right! That explains it.

Comment: also, don't cast the return value ... if you get compiler warnings without the cast then it's more likely to be telling you something useful that you need to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.c_str()` when passing a `std::string` to functions that expect a `char *`.

Answer (score -2):

there are two things here...

1. Compile time inclusion of C header in C++ file
2. Linking C compiled lib (zlib) with C++ program

for the first issue, your compiler is not able to see declaration of gzopen, there might be many reasons for that..

please check the declaration of functions gzopen in zlib.h

Make sure you need to include path to zlib.h in the arguments to g++ 
ex: `-I/usr/local/include/zlib.h`

Please follow the link below for developer documentation
http://www.zlib.net/manual.html
Please follow the help

For 2. Linking your C++ program with zlib, please use

```
extern "C" {
#include <zlib.h> 
}
```

Comment: You should never redefine the zlib versions.

Comment: thanks I just realized thats big mistake.. corrected my answer !! thank you

Comment: Your answer is wrong in so many details: 1) No need to have `extern "C" include...` because zlib is c++ aware and contains a c++ check already. You write that this step has something todo with linking, which is also wrong. Op has no problem to include zlib.h, no error message for this problem! So he have not to do any special thing for this!